# Reputable and reliable web service that integrates email + chat similar to Gmail/Hangouts?

Tags: email, chat

Google has been fumbling again and again in recent weeks.

Just now, it opened a stupid "upload your profile picture" window that wouldn't go away because apparently the UI doesn't understand what the "x" (close) button means.
I refreshed the page and it automatically switched over to the new (bad) Gmail interface despite the fact I ordered it to stay on the classic view.

Par for the course with arrogant Google: the "switch to classic view" button has been removed. As you already guessed, people are furious: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/oK8GilSPxxY/5qzpWzo1AAAJ

Then there are the unending data privacy scandals, which anyone who keeps up with tech news should know about. Just recently they were busted for failing to report a glitch that could have exposed large amounts of data from Google+ to third parties.

https://www.wsj.com/articles/google-exposed-user-data-feared-repercussions-of-disclosing-to-public-1539017194

So I'm looking for a serious alternative with the same functionality and none of the Google-specific arrogance, mishandling, and other shenanigans.